# Runlevel 3 with nomodeset in kernel to install CUDA 9.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, xserver

I am following instructions to install CUDA 9.0 from this link: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

and I am at the instruction:

> Reboot into runlevel 3 by temporarily adding the number "3" and the word
>   "nomodeset" to the end of the system's kernel boot parameters.

So from my understanding I boot up into GRUB, highlight the option "Start Ubuntu" and press 'E' and append to the `linux` line the following `'... 3 nomodeset '`

When I rebooted and appended that string to the end of the `linux` line and pressed F10, my start up froze at a purple-ish screen.

Essentially if I run the Cuda.run file directly without following the steps outlined in the guide the installer will fail stating that "X-Server" is still running and must be stopped. 
I have previously tried stopping X-Server but it caused me to brick my ubuntu boot so I won't be attempting anything like that soon.

How can I run level 3 with nomodeset so that I may carry out the CUDA 9.0 installation?
How can I troubleshoot whats causing the freeze on start up?

Thanks in advance!